# how to make this confirmation code work

Tags: command-line, bash

```
. confirm.sh
confirm
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
    echo “Jawaban YES OK” 
elif [ $? -eq 1 ]
then
    echo “Jawaban NO”
elif [ $? -eq 2 ]
    echo “Jawaban CONTINUE” 
fi
```

output

```
bash: contest.sh: line 11: syntax error near unexpected token `fi'
bash: contest.sh: line 11: `fi  '
```

[image: contest.sh]

Comment: Second `elif` doesn't have a `then` also all double-quotes should be replaced with `"`

Comment: thanks it solved ,but if $? = 2 the output is still NO

Answer (score 0):

You have to add "then" after second "elif".

```
...
elif [ $? -eq 2 ]
then
echo “Jawaban CONTINUE”
...
```